# rename a build in buildbot

Tags: python, buildbot

Is there a way to rename a build in buildbot without losing all of the logs?

For instance I have several windows slaves which all might build: "Windows 2008+ DEBUG" but I want to rename this build to: "Windows 2008R2+ DEBUG".

How do I set `compare_attr` (if that's even what I need to do) so that all of the logs/etc... are included from the previous builds in the new one.

Can I manually rename the directories and expect everything to work? Experimentation has told me that will not work but maybe I can write a command to change certain things?

Comment: Anybody have any ideas on this one? I've tried moving the files manually but I think I'm going to have to end up writing a script+filter to do this all for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the name of the directory, just the name of the builder, you can set the `builddir` attribute of the builder to be whatever it currently is, then name you builder however you want.

The data stored in the builder directory is in pickles. Looking at the code, I think the only data could cause issues is the builder name. If you done care about non-build events, you could probably just delete the `builder` file from each directory. Otherwise, rewriting the pickle with the update builder name should work.

Comment: Works as well as anything else for now. Will keep working on a better solution though.